Why is my 8-bit quantized model slower than my 16-bit model?
I've quantized my neural network tensorflow model to both 8-bit and 16-bit precision to improve performance, expecting the 8-bit version to be faster due to reduced memory and computational requirements. However, I’ve noticed that the 8-bit quantized model is actually slower than the 16-bit model during inference.
Here are the details for both models:
8-bit:
 Tensor serving_default_input_2:0 - dtype: \<class 'numpy.uint8'\>, shape: \[1 9\]  
Tensor FeedforwardNN/dense_3/MatMul;FeedforwardNN/dense_3/BiasAdd - dtype: \<class 'numpy.int32'\>, shape: \[4\]  
Tensor FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization_2/batchnorm/mul_1;FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization_2/batchnorm/add_1;FeedforwardNN/dense_3/MatMul;FeedforwardNN/dense_3/BiasAdd - dtype: \<class 'numpy.int8'\>, shape: \[ 4 20\]  
Tensor FeedforwardNN/dense_2/MatMul;FeedforwardNN/dense_2/BiasAdd - dtype: \<class 'numpy.int32'\>, shape: \[20\]  
Tensor FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization_1/batchnorm/mul_1;FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization_1/batchnorm/add_1;FeedforwardNN/dense_2/MatMul;FeedforwardNN/dense_2/BiasAdd - dtype: \<class 'numpy.int8'\>, shape: \[20 32\]  
Tensor FeedforwardNN/dense_1/MatMul;FeedforwardNN/dense_1/BiasAdd - dtype: \<class 'numpy.int32'\>, shape: \[32\]  
Tensor FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization/batchnorm/mul_1;FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization/batchnorm/add_1;FeedforwardNN/dense_1/MatMul;FeedforwardNN/dense_1/BiasAdd - dtype: \<class 'numpy.int8'\>, shape: \[32 32\]  
Tensor FeedforwardNN/dense/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp - dtype: \<class 'numpy.int32'\>, shape: \[32\]  
Tensor FeedforwardNN/dense/MatMul - dtype: \<class 'numpy.int8'\>, shape: \[32  9\]  
Tensor tfl.quantize - dtype: \<class 'numpy.int8'\>, shape: \[1 9\]  
Tensor FeedforwardNN/dense/MatMul;FeedforwardNN/dense/BiasAdd - dtype: \<class 'numpy.int8'\>, shape: \[ 1 32\]  
Tensor FeedforwardNN/dense/leaky_re_lu/LeakyRelu - dtype: \<class 'numpy.int8'\>, shape: \[ 1 32\]
Tensor FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization/batchnorm/mul_1;FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization/batchnorm/add_1;FeedforwardNN/dense_1/MatMul;FeedforwardNN/dense_1/BiasAdd1 - dtype: \<class 'numpy.int8'\>, shape: \[ 1 32\]  
Tensor FeedforwardNN/dense_1/leaky_re_lu_1/LeakyRelu - dtype: \<class 'numpy.int8'\>, shape: \[ 1 32\]
Tensor FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization_1/batchnorm/mul_1;FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization_1/batchnorm/add_1;FeedforwardNN/dense_2/MatMul;FeedforwardNN/dense_2/BiasAdd1 - dtype: \<class 'numpy.int8'\>, shape: \[ 1 20\]  
Tensor FeedforwardNN/dense_2/leaky_re_lu_2/LeakyRelu - dtype: \<class 'numpy.int8'\>, shape: \[ 1 20\]
Tensor FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization_2/batchnorm/mul_1;FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization_2/batchnorm/add_1;FeedforwardNN/dense_3/MatMul;FeedforwardNN/dense_3/BiasAdd1 - dtype: \<class 'numpy.int8'\>, shape: \[1 4\]  
Tensor StatefulPartitionedCall:01 - dtype: \<class 'numpy.int8'\>, shape: \[1 4\]  
Tensor StatefulPartitionedCall:0 - dtype: \<class 'numpy.uint8'\>, shape: \[1 4\]

16-bit:
Tensor serving_default_input_2:0 - dtype: \<class 'numpy.float32'\>, shape: \[1 9\]
Tensor FeedforwardNN/dense_1/MatMul;FeedforwardNN/dense_1/BiasAdd - dtype: \<class 'numpy.float16'\>, shape: \[32\]
Tensor FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization/batchnorm/mul_1;FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization/batchnorm/add_1;FeedforwardNN/dense_1/MatMul;FeedforwardNN/dense_1/BiasAdd - dtype: \<class 'numpy.float16'\>, shape: \[32 32\]
Tensor FeedforwardNN/dense_2/MatMul;FeedforwardNN/dense_2/BiasAdd - dtype: \<class 'numpy.float16'\>, shape: \[20\]
Tensor FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization_1/batchnorm/mul_1;FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization_1/batchnorm/add_1;FeedforwardNN/dense_2/MatMul;FeedforwardNN/dense_2/BiasAdd - dtype: \<class 'numpy.float16'\>, shape: \[20 32\]
Tensor FeedforwardNN/dense_3/MatMul;FeedforwardNN/dense_3/BiasAdd - dtype: \<class 'numpy.float16'\>, shape: \[4\]
Tensor FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization_2/batchnorm/mul_1;FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization_2/batchnorm/add_1;FeedforwardNN/dense_3/MatMul;FeedforwardNN/dense_3/BiasAdd - dtype: \<class 'numpy.float16'\>, shape: \[ 4 20\]
Tensor FeedforwardNN/dense/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp - dtype: \<class 'numpy.float16'\>, shape: \[32\]
Tensor FeedforwardNN/dense/MatMul - dtype: \<class 'numpy.float16'\>, shape: \[32  9\]
Tensor FeedforwardNN/dense_1/MatMul;FeedforwardNN/dense_1/BiasAdd1 - dtype: \<class 'numpy.float32'\>, shape: \[32\]
Tensor FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization/batchnorm/mul_1;FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization/batchnorm/add_1;FeedforwardNN/dense_1/MatMul;FeedforwardNN/dense_1/BiasAdd1 - dtype: \<class 'numpy.float32'\>, shape: \[32 32\]
Tensor FeedforwardNN/dense_2/MatMul;FeedforwardNN/dense_2/BiasAdd1 - dtype: \<class 'numpy.float32'\>, shape: \[20\]
Tensor FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization_1/batchnorm/mul_1;FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization_1/batchnorm/add_1;FeedforwardNN/dense_2/MatMul;FeedforwardNN/dense_2/BiasAdd1 - dtype: \<class 'numpy.float32'\>, shape: \[20 32\]
Tensor FeedforwardNN/dense_3/MatMul;FeedforwardNN/dense_3/BiasAdd1 - dtype: \<class 'numpy.float32'\>, shape: \[4\]
Tensor FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization_2/batchnorm/mul_1;FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization_2/batchnorm/add_1;FeedforwardNN/dense_3/MatMul;FeedforwardNN/dense_3/BiasAdd1 - dtype: \<class 'numpy.float32'\>, shape: \[ 4 20\]
Tensor FeedforwardNN/dense/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp1 - dtype: \<class 'numpy.float32'\>, shape: \[32\]
Tensor FeedforwardNN/dense/MatMul1 - dtype: \<class 'numpy.float32'\>, shape: \[32  9\]
Tensor FeedforwardNN/dense/MatMul;FeedforwardNN/dense/BiasAdd - dtype: \<class 'numpy.float32'\>, shape: \[ 1 32\]
Tensor FeedforwardNN/dense/leaky_re_lu/LeakyRelu - dtype: \<class 'numpy.float32'\>, shape: \[ 1 32\]
Tensor FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization/batchnorm/mul_1;FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization/batchnorm/add_1;FeedforwardNN/dense_1/MatMul;FeedforwardNN/dense_1/BiasAdd2 - dtype: \<class 'numpy.float32'\>, shape: \[ 1 32\]
Tensor FeedforwardNN/dense_1/leaky_re_lu_1/LeakyRelu - dtype: \<class 'numpy.float32'\>, shape: \[ 1 32\]
Tensor FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization_1/batchnorm/mul_1;FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization_1/batchnorm/add_1;FeedforwardNN/dense_2/MatMul;FeedforwardNN/dense_2/BiasAdd2 - dtype: \<class 'numpy.float32'\>, shape: \[ 1 20\]
Tensor FeedforwardNN/dense_2/leaky_re_lu_2/LeakyRelu - dtype: \<class 'numpy.float32'\>, shape: \[ 1 20\]
Tensor FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization_2/batchnorm/mul_1;FeedforwardNN/batch_normalization_2/batchnorm/add_1;FeedforwardNN/dense_3/MatMul;FeedforwardNN/dense_3/BiasAdd2 - dtype: \<class 'numpy.float32'\>, shape: \[1 4\]
Tensor StatefulPartitionedCall:0 - dtype: \<class 'numpy.float32'\>, shape: \[1 4\]

This is my test:
This snippet of code takes 3.8s:
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="8bit_model.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

def evaluate_quantized_model8bit(X_test):
    predicted_labels = []
    for i in range(len(X_test)):
        input_data = X_test[i].reshape(1, -1).astype(np.uint8)  
        interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)
        interpreter.invoke()
        output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
        predicted_label = np.argmax(output_data)
        predicted_labels.append(predicted_label)
    return predicted_labels


predicted_labelsQ = evaluate_quantized_model(test_data)

And this other one takes 1.1s:
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="16bit_model.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

def evaluate_quantized_model16bit(X_test):
    predicted_labels = []
    for i in range(len(X_test)):
        input_data = X_test[i].reshape(1, -1).astype(np.float32)  
        interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)
        interpreter.invoke()
        output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
        predicted_label = np.argmax(output_data)
        predicted_labels.append(predicted_label)
    return predicted_labels


predicted_labelsQ = evaluate_quantized_model(test_data)

Why does this happen?

Everything related to performace and precision heavily depends on your hardware, usually only the newer GPUs have full support for INT8 ops. Which device are you running?
